# Allocate multiple workers to the same queue in resque

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

I need to add a new resque queue to an existing RoR application that is already deployed in production. It would be more difficult to change how the workers are started (because it will require a change in the deployment process).

I am wondering if there is a way to configure the workers allocated to the queue directly in the configuration for resque.

I know that I can configure the queues in the resque.yml file, but I did not find how to specify how many workers to allocate to each queue.